# How to request body object included file in Array at Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm in trouble

How do I get the following data format in Spring Boot?

```
Example:
   [
     {name:"fileName", file: file1},
     {name:"fileName", file: file2},
     {name:"fileName", file: file3},
     ....
   ]
```

Comment: Can you please add some code, so we can better address our suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use produces in post call like below:

```
  @PostMapping(value = "/save", produces=MediaType. APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE, consumes = MediaType. APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
          public void updateCharacters(@RequestBody List<Character> character) {
            log.log(Level.INFO, "{} characters have been saved", characters.getCharacters().size());
          }
```